# Change background color of ListView in VB6

Tags: vb6, listview

I'm working with some legacy code and need to change the background color of a row (and the font color) in a ListView in VB6 based on some criteria.  I need to change the color of the row when the row is selected and not selected.  I can change the font color of a non-selected row via the .Foreground property but I can't change the color in any of the other scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color of selected rows is controlled by the system. You cannot change it to anything else.

If you *have* to be able to change the background of the selected rows, you will need to custom draw the listview -- which, to be honest, is too much of a pain to seriously consider :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [forum post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=510389).  Here's an sample from the code which colors every other row:

```
'\\ loop through the rows to select every other row
For i = 1 To lvwBackColour.ListItems.Count
    If (lvwBackColour.ListItems(i).Index Mod 2) = 0 Then

        '\\ add a tick to the checkbox
        lvwBackColour.ListItems(i).Checked = True

        '\\ add the colour to the picturebox
        '\\ See Here (http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa230480(VS.60).aspx)
        '\\ for information about the Line method
        picBG.Line (0, i - 1)-(1, i), &H4000FF, BF

        '\\ update column four caption
        lvwBackColour.ListItems(i).SubItems(3) = "Hidden column value = 1"

    Else
        '\\ remove the tick from the checkbox
        lvwBackColour.ListItems(i).Checked = False

        '\\ reset backcolour to white
        picBG.Line (0, i - 1)-(1, i), &HFFFFFF, BF

        '\\ reset the Column Four caption
        lvwBackColour.ListItems(i).SubItems(3) = "Hidden column value = 0"
    End If
Next i

'\\ set the listview to use the picturebox image
lvwBackColour.Picture = picBG.Image
```

Here's the [link](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa230480(VS.60).aspx) to the msdn article which talks about the Line method.