# Listview Backcolor

Tags: listview, vb6

I am using vb 6.0 and i want to change the back color of the selected item.

in Default by windows,the back color is blue, how can I customize the color.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478421/change-background-color-of-listview-in-vb6

Comment: Yes, you need to subclass and handle custom (not owner) drawing which asks your app for any changes to each component it draws.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is something you have a real need to do you may want to live with the default system color. There is no property for this so you'll need to dip into the API. If you still want to do it here is a site with a link to an application that will get you started.

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/indepth-vb6-listbox-tutorial