# VB6 Change Background Colour of ListView Item

Tags: vb6

Refering to [Change background color of listview in vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478421/change-background-color-of-listview-in-vb6)

I tried this example and does not work as in I see no coloured rows.
I have a command button on my form that loads listview items then once that is finished I call the routine to setup the colour.
I made my picture box visible to see the expected outcome and it is as expected. So effectively setting the ListView's Picture property to the PictureBox's Image property is doing nothing for me.

Anyhow this is my code:

```
'pbxBG.Visible = True
If lsvPersonalisation.ListItems.Count <> 0 Then

    pbxBG.Width = lsvPersonalisation.Width
    pbxBG.Height = lsvPersonalisation.ListItems(1).Height * (lsvPersonalisation.ListItems.Count)
    pbxBG.ScaleHeight = lsvPersonalisation.ListItems.Count
    pbxBG.ScaleWidth = 1
    pbxBG.DrawWidth = 1
    pbxBG.Cls
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To lsvPersonalisation.ListItems.Count
        If lsvPersonalisation.ListItems(i).Tag = "1" Then
            pbxBG.Line (0, i - 1)-(1, i), &H80FFFF, BF
        Else
            pbxBG.Line (0, i - 1)-(1, i), &HFFFFFF, BF
        End If
    Next i
Else
    pbxBG.Cls
End If
lsvPersonalisation.Picture = pbxBG.Image
'pbxBG.Visible = False
```

Comment: try chaning the AutoRedraw-Property of your pcxBG-Control...

Comment: @AKDADEVIL I suggest you put your comment about setting `AutoRedraw = True` for `PictureBox` as an answer.

Comment: @AKDADEVIL retested and this worked thanks. So do as ilya kurnosiv said so I mark as answered.